# Determine MS Excel file type with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to determine MS Office Excel file type in Apache POI? I need to know in what format is the Excel file: in Excel '97(-2007) (.xls) or Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx).

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
int type = PoiTypeHelper.getType(file);
switch (type) {
case PoiType.EXCEL_1997_2007:
   ...
   break;
case PoiType.EXCEL_2007:
   ...
   break;
default:
   ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know up front? Can you not just use WorkbookFactory and have it create the appropriate type for you?

Comment: This is also a good variant, thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

If you're going to be doing something special with the files, then [rjokelai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522441/determine-ms-excel-file-type-with-apache-poi/14522512#14522512) is the way to do it.

However, if you're just going to be using the HSSF / XSSF / Common SS usermodel, then it's much simpler to have POI do it for you, and use [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) to have the type detected and opened for you. You'd do something like:

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("something.xls"));
```

or

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(request.getInputStream());
```

Then if you needed to do something special, test if it's a `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook`. When opening the file, [use a File rather than an InputStream if possible](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) to speed things up and save memory.

If you don't know what your file is at all, use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to do the detection - it can detect a huge number of different file formats for you.

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
// For .xlsx
POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file) ));

// For .xls
POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(file) ));
```

These are essentially the methods that the `WorkbookFactory#create(InputStream)` uses for determining the type

Please note, that both method supports only streams supporting "mark" feature (or PushBackInputStream), so simple FileInputStream is not supported. Use BufferedInputStream as a wrapper. For this reason after the detection you can simply reuse the stream, since it will be reseted to the starting point.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only way to detect file type when you are using low level Event based read only access to process large excel files.

Comment: Added the information that only "mark" supporting streams can be used. Updated code sample.

Comment: method `hasOOXMLHeader` is depricated within class `POIXMLDocument`, use it within class [DocumentFactoryHelper](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DocumentFactoryHelper.html)

Comment: Deprecated methods

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the **FileMagic** class. See below JavaDoc -
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/FileMagic.html

**Sample code snippet:**

`FileMagic.valueOf(inputStream).equals(FileMagic.OOXML) // XLSX`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lib implementation of `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory#create(java.io.InputStream)`

We can mimic the `WorkbookFactory`'s logic, remove irrelevant bits and return file type instead.

```
public static TYPE fileType(File file) {
    try (
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file)
    ) {
        if (!(inp).markSupported()) {
            return getNotMarkSupportFileType(file);
        }
        return getType(inp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Analyse FileType Problem.", e);
        return TYPE.INVALID;
    }
}

private static TYPE getNotMarkSupportFileType(File file) throws IOException {
    try (
            InputStream inp = new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 8)
    ) {
        return getType(inp);
    }
}

private static TYPE getType(InputStream inp) throws IOException {
    byte[] header8 = IOUtils.peekFirst8Bytes(inp);
    if (NPOIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(header8)) {
        NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(inp);
        return fileType(fs);
    } else if (DocumentFactoryHelper.hasOOXMLHeader(inp)) {
        return TYPE.XSSF_WORKBOOK;
    }
    return TYPE.INVALID;
}

private static TYPE fileType(NPOIFSFileSystem fs) {
    DirectoryNode root = fs.getRoot();
    if (root.hasEntry("EncryptedPackage")) {
        return TYPE.XSSF_WORKBOOK;
    }
    return TYPE.HSSF_WORKBOOK;

}

public enum TYPE {
    HSSF_WORKBOOK, XSSF_WORKBOOK, INVALID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i have identified the requested file is of Office type.

```
public static boolean isOfficeDoc(String filePath) {
         FileMagic fileMagic = getFileMagicObj(filePath);
            return fileMagic != null && (fileMagic == FileMagic.OLE2 || fileMagic == FileMagic.OOXML);
        }

    private static FileMagic getFileMagicObj(String filePath) {

        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
             InputStream magicIS = FileMagic.prepareToCheckMagic(is)) {

            return FileMagic.valueOf(magicIS);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```