# Correct way to distinguish .xls from .doc file?

Tags: java, excel, format, apache-poi

I searched how to detect that file is `.xls` and I've found a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522512/2674303) (but not deprecated):
**POIFSFileSystem:**

```
@Deprecated
@Removal(version="4.0")
public static boolean hasPOIFSHeader(InputStream inp) throws IOException {
    return FileMagic.valueOf(inp) == FileMagic.OLE2;
}
```

But this one returns true for all microsoft word documents for example for `.doc`

Is there a way to detect `.xls` document?

Comment: Have a look at the source of [EmbeddedExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/extractor/EmbeddedExtractor.html)

Comment: @kiwiwings You seem experienced with Apache POI. Wouldn't it be enough to check something like `POIFSFileSystem(inputStream).getRoot().getStorageClsid().equals(ClassID.EXCEL97)`? Since I don't know the file format well I couldn't be sure that it is reliable or not.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Beside the `ClassID`, I would also check for `DirectoryNode` names - see the `BiffExtractor` in [EmbeddedExtractor](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/ss/extractor/EmbeddedExtractor.java). Not every program, which outputs .xls/.doc, sets the ClassId correct. Be aware that there are multiple `DirectoryNode` names for e.g. Excel (see [`InternalWorkbook`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/model/InternalWorkbook.java)`.WORKBOOK_DIR_ENTRY_NAMES`)

Comment: Is it an option to use Apache Tika? https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: @Nathanael Tika usesPOI internally

Comment: Yes, if you could use Tika you can use the MimeType detection. Or you can look in the source code how they implemented it. E.g. the POIFSContainerDetector

Comment: @Nathanael, I can use Tika.

Comment: The `file` command (cygwin) seems to differentiate these. You use it via ProcessBuilder or use its code  to do file magic check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both .doc/.xls documents can are stored in the OLE2 storage format. The `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic` helps you to detect the file storage format only and not sufficient alone to distinguish between .doc/.xls files.

Also it does not appear that there is any direct API available in POI library to determine the document type (excel or document) for given inputstream/file.

Below example my be helpful to determine if given stream is a valid .xls (or .xlsx)file with the caveat that it read the given inputstram and close it.

```
    // slurp content from given input and close it
    public static boolean isExcelFile(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        try {
            // it slurp the input stream
            Workbook workbook = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(in);
            workbook.close();
            return true;

        } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException | org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You may found more information on excel file format on [this link](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf)

**Update** 
Solution based on [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) as suggested by [gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr):

```
public class TikaBasedFileTypeDetector {
    private Tika tika;
    private TemporaryResources temporaryResources;

    public void init() {
        this.tika = new Tika();
        this.temporaryResources = new TemporaryResources();
    }

    // clean up all the temporary resources
    public void destroy() throws IOException {
        temporaryResources.close();
    }

    // return content mime type
    public String detectType(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(in, temporaryResources);

        return tika.detect(tikaInputStream);
    }

    public boolean isExcelFile(InputStream in) throws IOException{
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/1700467 for information on mimetypes
        String type = detectType(in);
        return type.startsWith("application/vnd.ms-excel") || //for Micorsoft document
                type.startsWith("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml"); // for OpenOffice xml format
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/1700467) on mime types.

Comment: You need to give Tika the whole file via a `TikaInputStream` if you want it to do Container-aware detection to get the OLE2 subtype, to work out if it's DOC or XLS, you can't get that from Mime Magic alone

Comment: try catch blocks should never be used as an if statement

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [Apache POI's](http://poi.apache.org/) -  [HSSF module](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). 
That model (library) is written to read and write xls files (and latest for xlsx as well - although these are different languages). 
With this code...

```
InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("FileNameWithLink.xls");
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

...you can detect if it is **readable** xls file. 
Going deeper you can use [this code](https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272) to try reading it etc. Actually that module is really easy to use. 
There can be situations that it technically is `.xls` file, but it may not be readable (there can be various problems with it).
Extra - XSSF is for `.xlsx` and HSSF is for `.xls`. 
 
I haven't used other techniques as I always want to be sure that I will be able read that file later.

Comment: I noticed that this lib throws different exceptions for .doc file, for encrypted xls and for pdf. I want to distinquisg these cases

Comment: could you explain for my tired brain a bit more? distinguish more? aren't those different exceptions distinguishing those cases enough?

Comment: I just noticed for these types. I am not sure that  for some another type I will see same exception

Answer (score 2):

You can use [docx4j](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j). Load the file with [OpcPackage.load()](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.docx4j/docx4j/3.3.1/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage.html) and then check the content type.

OpcPackage.load()

```
 * Convenience method to create a WordprocessingMLPackage
 * or PresentationMLPackage
 * from an inputstream (.docx/.docxm, .ppxtx or Flat OPC .xml).
 * It detects the convenient format inspecting two first bytes of stream (magic bytes). 
 * For office 2007 'x' formats, these two bytes are 'PK' (same as zip file)
```

load() returns a OpcPackage which is the abstract class that GloxPackage, PresentationMLPackage, SpreadsheetMLPackage, WordprocessingMLPackage are based on.   So this should work for word, excel and powerpoint docs.

A basic check

```
public final String XLSX_FILE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.main+xml";
public final String WORD_FILE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml";
public final String UNKNOWN_FILE = "UNKNOWN";



public boolean isFileXLSX(String fileLocation) {
    return getContentTypeFromFile(fileLocation).equals(XLSX_FILE);
}


public String getContentTypeFromFile(String fileLocation) {
    try {
        return OpcPackage.load(new File(fileLocation)).getContentType();
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        return UNKNOWN_FILE;
    }
}
```

You should see values like

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.main+xml
```

Comment: Is it unversal solution for all file types?

Comment: i added some more details.  this should work for word, excel and powerpoint - any format that docx4j supports.  I have only tested that code above with a .docx and .xlsx files.

Comment: Actually I want to have the method which accept file and return true if it is excel and false in other cases. It can be .doc, .pdf, ..exe and so on

Comment: hmm.. so after adding some more code i realize you wrote '.doc / .xls'  - the old office format. i'm pretty sure this method only works on the 'x' format - the xml based formats.