# how do I check a file is a valid xlsx file in java without opening with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, file-type

In java (jdk 1.6) is there a way to check a file is a valid xlsx without opening the entire file with POI or other API. Currently we use Apache POI in the project to open the file - basically we create a new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream) and if that throws an exception it is not a valid xlsx. However we found one xlsx file which is 8MB is taking 1GB memory to open for some reason and actually caused a production outage on our servers. We can not rely on the file extension as someone can take a file which is not xlsx like a php file and rename with xlsx extension. I'm looking for some option which has minimal memory impacts - ideally not opening the file at all.

Its too much of a risk if a single file upload can kill the server but we also still need to validate the file is in fact an xlsx.

Comment: avoid tools that use the new poi 4.0.0 release as it only supports Java 8 - have a look at https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader - it supports poi 3.17 and therefore can be used with Java 6

Comment: Define "valid xlsx" - depending on your requirements here (from "looks like something in a zip" to "opens without error in Excel") the solution will vary!

Comment: And whether you also consider xlsm, xlsb, xls (and older formats) valid Excel workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what your file is at all, use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to do the detection - it can detect a huge number of different file formats for you.

[Determine MS Excel file type with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522441/determine-ms-excel-file-type-with-apache-poi)

here are some examples https://www.baeldung.com/apache-tika

Comment: Specifically, use Tika content detection https://tika.apache.org/1.19/detection.html using tika-mimetypes.xml (or build your own xml for just the formats you care about) https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L2350

Comment: @IceArdor You can't tell the difference between a `.zip` and a `.xlsx` or a `.odp` (for example) with mime magic alone, you'd need Apache Tika's zip-aware detector for that (available as standard via `DefaultDetector`)

Comment: @Gagravarr absolutely right! https://tika.apache.org/1.19/api/org/apache/tika/detect/DefaultDetector.html and https://tika.apache.org/1.19/detection.html#Container_Aware_Detection