# xlsx file created with apache poi cannot be opened

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `Apache POI 3.17` to create `xlsx` files and filling it with data from the db. The file gets created fine but when I try to open it, I get 'incompatible format' error even though when I inspect the file, I can see that it is a Microsoft spreadsheet file. I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397347/file-excel-from-apache-poi-cant-open-by-ms-excel-corrupt),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522441/determine-ms-excel-file-type-with-apache-poi/14522512#14522512) and [here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewSheet) and tried all these examples but didn't help and I don't know where the problem is. Here is my file creation code:

```
File excelFile = new File("C:\\myFile.xlsx"); //a new file to be created
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
Cell cell;
//some font and style creation
for(String eachHeader : headers) {
        cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
        cell.setCellValue(eachHeader);
        cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        cellIndex++;
}
//some more row and cell creation

try {
    //finally try to write all this content into the excel file
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    logger.debug("Worksheet created: " + excelFile.getAbsolutePath());
}catch(Exception exc) {
        logger.error("Error occured while creating or writing to the excel file: " + exc.getMessage());

}
```

Again, the file is created fine with some data in it as I can see that the size is not 0, but just cannot open it, why??

Comment: You should probably also close the workbook. Also, does it work if you don't write the `//some more row and cell creation` part?

Comment: i tried closing workbook as well, and no it still doesnt work without any data, still cannot open the file

Comment: What excel version do you use?

Comment: I use OpenOffice 4 but we tried it on different PCs with various versions of MS Excel as well @XtremeBaumer

Comment: According to [this forum post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=67299), you would need excel and not open office to open that file. The minimum excel version to open that kind of file is 2007 and above